# Rails STI getting parent class instead of child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, sti

Here is my code:

```
  def data
    providers.map do |provider|
      binding.pry
      [
        ERB::Util.h(provider.id),
        link_to(raw(image_tag provider.avatar_url(:small), class: 'img-responsive'), admin_provider_path(provider))provider.enabled))
      ]
    end
  end

  def providers
    @providers ||= fetch_providers
  end

  def fetch_providers
    providers = Provider.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    providers = providers.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      providers = providers.where("email like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    providers
  end
```

My Problem is, I always get nil from `provider.avatar_url(:small)`. After I debug this `provider` using pry like this:

```
provider.class.name
=> "User"
```

I have defined the `providers` variable to taken from `Provider` not `User`

```
providers = Provider.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
```

I can't get `"Provider"` class. Which of course carrierwave will search the file using **user upload directory** not **provider upload directory**. How do I get this? Thanks in advance

My STI class:

```
class Provider < User
  has_many :products
  after_create :assign_default_role
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def self.all
    User.with_role(:provider)
  end

  private

  def assign_default_role
    self.add_role "provider"
  end
end
```

Comment: I assume you do have a `type` column in your table?

Comment: no, I dont have it, should I add it? im using devise with rolify gem

Comment: `type` column is a must if you want to use STI, otherwise rails have no idea what type  given record is supposed to be. You will need to add it and put `Provider` to all records representing providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if you are using STI without having a `type` column in your table. When loading record from database, ActiveRecord is using information in that column to determine the class which is to be used to instantiate the object.

To fix, you will need to add the missing column and populate with a `Provider` for every record representing a subclass.